# What does it mean to have JavaScript that renders both on server and browser?

Tags: javascript

I often see people saying that one of the benefits of JavaScript is that you can have one code-base that works on both the server and browser. I've never had code that I re-used for both back-end and front-end in any of my node.js projects, though. If I'm writing a web server in node that serves up some static assets for a front-end app in Angular, most of my back-end code is specific to non-front-end tasks.

So what does it mean, or look like, to have code that you use on both back and front end? A concrete example is that I often see people saying that React renders both on server and browser. Great! How does this help, though? Is this strictly for automated testing?

Comment: i love JS, but front/back code uniformity is not really important. that said, i do use mustache a lot because it can turn the same template into html in js/php/other, and it reduces some repetition, or makes providing a no-js version of a SPA easier.

Comment: Or feasible, for anything but trivial code (OK, and maybe templates).  Server-side JS doesn't have much in the way of built-in DOM stuff, AFAICR.

Comment: This is not the kind of question that we have Stackoverflow for. It's one of the explicitly mentioned "this question is off-topic" over at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: IMO Javascript on server side is not necessity, but if you know it inside out than you can do a lot of nifty things on client side without learning any new technology.

Answer (score 2):

The general case for wanting code to run on both the client and the server is so that you can have:

- A fast, client-side implementation
- A reliable, server-side implementation

So you can have code that checks user input to make sure it is OK and have it run on the client so that the user gets instant feedback and run the same code on the server so the user can't bypass it and get bad input into your system.

Or you can have complex code that runs on the client to build a page using lots of Ajax and the history API while having it duplicated on the backend so it still works for clients where the JavaScript fails (due to a bad connection or lack of support (e.g. from search engines)) and so that if a page other than the homepage is loaded the browser will load the right page instead of loading the homepage and then (probably not-quite immediately) replacing it with the desired page.